# How does this script use `push` on an `Object`?

Tags: javascript

In the analytics script below, I see that `window.heap` is initialized as an `Array`.

After the first expression evaluates, the new `Array` is assigned a `load` function, which is executed immediately.

The resulting `window.heap` is an `Object`.

Overall I think I'm confused about what's happening here because we start with an `Array`, given it a non-array attribute, add string indexes to it (`heap[p[o]]) = n(p[o])`) and then magically have an `Object` with `<string: function>` key value pairs.

How can this be? What nuanced piece am I missing?

If I had to boil it down to one question that would help me understand: **What would this Javascript snippet look like in TypeScript or Go?**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (window.heap = window.heap || []),
        (heap.load = function (e, t) {
            (window.heap.appid = e), (window.heap.config = t = t || {});
            var r = document.createElement("script");
            (r.type = "text/javascript"), (r.async = !0), (r.src = "https://cdn.heapanalytics.com/js/heap-" + e + ".js");
            var a = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
            a.parentNode.insertBefore(r, a);
            for (
                var n = function (e) {
                        return function () {
                            heap.push([e].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)));
                        };
                    },
                    p = ["addEventProperties", "addUserProperties", "clearEventProperties", "identify", "resetIdentity", "removeEventProperty", "setEventProperties", "track", "unsetEventProperty"],
                    o = 0;
                o < p.length;
                o++
            )
                heap[p[o]] = n(p[o]);
        });
    heap.load("some-app-id");
</script>
```

Comment: It's still an array. The console is lying to you.

Comment: Arrays are just specialized objects and can have additional properties applied to them. `typeof []` returns `'object'`

Comment: not even special objects really, they're just objects. if the dev tools say it's an object type, it's because it's been given object-like properties. we just get some special syntax to create and use them in the code, in the background they're just objects. (if you to typeof on any array, it will say 'object', and it has a prototype and all of that.)

Comment: Basically `[1,2]` is just a special object `{ "0": 1, "1": 2, length: 2 }` that you can access using numeric indexes. To test for an array, use `Array.isArray(arr)`.

Comment: "*What would this Javascript snippet look like in TypeScript*" - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/56467368/1048572 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/53296047/1048572 (although with fixed properties, not arbitrary strings)